# Activity Recognition API for Android wear or other Java open source API

Tags: google-play-services, wear-os, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, activity-recognition

We are using Google Activity Recognition tools, i.e. Google Play Services and Google Fit for our Android Wear app.
Google changes its API frequently, with no backward compatibility, every couple of months we should change our code.
I would like to know if there is an "open source" activity recognition available, either as Android Library or pure Java ?

Comment: Aside from the [ActivityRecognitionApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi) in the docs, I haven't seen an open-source file from Google.

Comment: We use this one, I am looking for something else.